# django project always trying (and failing) to load file in separate app

Tags: django

I'm going back to an old django project and am trying to make a new site in a new app I just made, popularify. I want to load an httpResponse and nothing else when I go to the /popularify path , but it keeps trying and failing to get a favicon.ico file, the 404 error always appears in the chrome web console and django logs.

I have it set up correctly so my popularify page loads a basic httpResponse:

my main urls.py file in my project folder has a path:

```
path('popularify/', include('popularify.urls')),
```

The popularify app urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And the popularify views.py file looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

All very basic to just load some text, but in console I am getting a unrelated 404 error trying to load a file I never directly specified, and dont want to load:

[image]

If I click the favicon.ico link it shows the html file  _base.html I have in my templates folder, a file I use as a base file in my pages/ app, which is completely separate and something I don't want to load in my new popularify app. Do I need to tell my popularify path to specifically not use this _base.html file in my templates folder?

Comment: in your base.html add what ever things you want to show in all pages, for example a footer. You can create a  separate home.html file to show your favicon icon

Comment: tried deleting the base.html and am still getting favicon.ico 404 not found concole error

Comment: dont delete the base.html, create a home.html and add favicon ico there, all the templates has to inherit form base.html  (as a good practice)